# Detecting the respiratory rate of a breating lung.

Tags: signal-processing, curves

I am currently working with some data-sets that represents the movements of a beating heart and breathing lungs.

The data-sets are represented as a collection of floats that range from 47 to 51. We sample approximatly 70-100 of these values pr. second and they represent the change in movement of the organs.

Below is a sample of the respiratory rate. It shows how the lung expand and contract durning  a period of 29 seconds.
[image: Respiratory]

I have a strong fundament in Informatics and Techology - but a weak fundament in Mathematics. I know how I can achieve my goals by writing computer algorithms - but I want to go deeper and explore the domain of mathematics. Simply to challenge myself - and to learn something new.

Based on the image above and with the knowledge that this should be done in real-time, I am interested in achieving the following goals:

A. I want to clean up the signal. It would be of benefit to remove some of the unwanted noise - on the fly - in real time - and maybe with some continious adaptation.

B. I wonder how i can detect if the curve is going upwards, downwards or if it is flat (person is holding his breath).

C. I wonder how much time it took for the person to perform a full inhalation and exhalation cycle

It would be of great help if I could get some input/directions towards the subjects i should study in order to achieve some - or all of these goals. I am sorry if this issue seems elementary. I am simply a late bloomer when it comes to math.

Comment: I'd start with the [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). Once you have a clean estimate of the signal, the derivative estimate (inhale/exhale) and period estimate (full inhale/exhale cycle) shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I don't know about the Kalman filter (I have only heard the name of it before). Is that suitable for a periodic waveform where any model or signal processing technique ought to build in the fact that the curve undergoes regular changes of direction?

Comment: @TooTone Sort of. For nonlinear processes like yours, you would you use what is called the Extended Kalman Filter. You can find lots of material on tracking a time-varying sine wave with an EKF. For example, [here](https://www.google.com/#q=extended+kalman+filter+sinusoid+tracking).

Comment: that looks like a nice reference from @AnonSubmitter85. The other thing you might want to look at is the signal processing stackexchange (maybe also the statistics one?)